# Filter and Sort Array of Docs in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array which holds information about availability and some other info about products. Instead of returning the all Data in Array i want to only return docs in array where the avail = true and then return all sorted by the id.

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "avail": true,
        "name": "product A",
        "qty": 18
    }, {
        "id": 9,
        "avail": false,
        "name": "product B",
        "qty": 0
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "avail": true,
        "name": "product C",
        "qty": 3
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "avail": true,
        "name": "product D",
        "qty": 47
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "avail": false,
        "name": "product E",
        "qty": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: When you see that three people answer within 3 minutes of your question, you know that you have asked something you could have googled in less than 3 minutes. (Instead of answering, those 3 should really have voted to have this question closed as duplicate, or at least link to a dupe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const result = original.filter(x => x.avail);
result.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can get only the records having `avail: true` by calling [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the data array. Next, sort those results using [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and comparing the `id` value of each array element.

Here's an example:

```js
const getAvailableProducts = allProducts => allProducts.filter(el => el.avail).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

const available = getAvailableProducts([{
  "id": 5,
  "avail": true,
  "name": "product A",
  "qty": 18
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "avail": false,
  "name": "product B",
  "qty": 0
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "avail": true,
  "name": "product C",
  "qty": 3
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "avail": true,
  "name": "product D",
  "qty": 47
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "avail": false,
  "name": "product E",
  "qty": 0
}]);

console.log('The following products are available:');
console.log(available);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and `sort` to accomplish this:

```
var arr = [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "avail": true,
        "name": "product A",
        "qty": 18
    }, {
        "id": 9,
        "avail": false,
        "name": "product B",
        "qty": 0
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "avail": true,
        "name": "product C",
        "qty": 3
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "avail": true,
        "name": "product D",
        "qty": 47
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "avail": false,
        "name": "product E",
        "qty": 0
    }
];

var newArr = arr.filter(a => {
    return a.avail;
}).sort((a, b) => {
    return a.id > b.id;
});

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 5,
  "avail": true,
  "name": "product A",
  "qty": 18
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "avail": false,
  "name": "product B",
  "qty": 0
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "avail": true,
  "name": "product C",
  "qty": 3
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "avail": true,
  "name": "product D",
  "qty": 47
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "avail": false,
  "name": "product E",
  "qty": 0
}];

const filteredData = data.filter(x => x.avail).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
console.log(filteredData);
```